# Remove nested Web Site in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, dotnetnuke

I'm trying to get DotNetNuke set up. I had to update the ActiveDirectory authentication module, so at one point I had it publish to my DotNetNuke solution. I've since changed my mind on how I want to do that, but I can't seem to get rid of it!

How can I delete the ActiveDirectory 'Web Site' below? It doesn't exist on file or in the solution, and I don't see anything obvious in IIS, but it won't go away. I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

[image: What I see in Visual Studio]

Answer (score 1):

I would think that it exists as a Virtual Directory in IIS, if you expand that folder (authentication services) do you see the ActiveDirectory folder with a different icon than the other folders in IIS?

If that's not it, you might open up the SLN file itself in Notepad and search for that ActiveDirectory folder, see if it is listed there.

You really shouldn't be opening the DNN website anyways, I highly recommend if you're doing DNN development you ditch the "website" model and run the Web Application Project model for development. Start with this tutorial http://www.christoc.com/Tutorials/All-Tutorials/aid/1

edit: After you have your development environment setup with DNN running at DNNDEV.ME you would then install visual studio templates -> http://www.christoc.com/Tutorials/All-Tutorials/aid/2

Comment: It's not in the .sln and there's nothing special in IIS. As a note, the tutorial you link to doesn't mention anything about using Web Application for developing in DNN, so I think it's misleading.

Comment: Converting to a Web Application will solve the problem, but I'm thinking others with this problem will be looking for a different solution, so I'm going to leave the question open for now.

Comment: Sorry, the tutorial is the beginning on how to get started with your development environment to do web app development. It is the first of a few, I'll update with additional linkage

Comment: I noticed the templates; they don't mention anything about Web Site vs Web Application. You might need a new tutorial on setting up DotNetNuke as a Web Application in Visual Studio. **nudge** **nudge**

Comment: Time prevents me from getting much more going, unfortunately. Anyways, I am not suggesting you make DNN itself WAP, but that any development you do for DNN should be WAP